# Updating multiple SQL rows with PHP and HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have a table with rows in an SQL database that I want to be able to change the values for. I have built a form that has a select option built in so a row of data can be changed in the database. I want the ability to be able to change multiple rows at the same time in a database by just submitting one form. This is my code to create the form and the table with php. I can figure out how to get all the values over to the updatedb.php page, but from there I don't know how to update multiple rows in the database.

```
<form action="updatedb.php" method="POST">
<tbody>
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "******";
 $password = "******";
 $dbname = "database";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '$value'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $test = $row["value3"];
 $test2 =$row["value5"];

 if ($row["status"] == "Value1") { $status1 = 'selected'; } else { $status1 = ''; }

 if ($row["status"] == "Value2") { $status2 = 'selected'; } else { $status2 = ''; }

 if ($row["status"] == "Value3") { $status3 = 'selected'; } else { $status3 = ''; }

 if ($row["status"] == "Value4") { $status4 = 'selected'; } else { $status4 = ''; }

 if ($row["status"] == "Value5") { $status5 = 'selected'; } else { $status5 = ''; }

 //This is the table that is created
 echo " 
 <tr><td>" . $row["value"] . $row["value2"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["value3"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["value4"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["value5"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["value6"] . "</td>
 <td>" . $row["value7"] . "</td>

<td>
 <select name='status[]' required>
  <option $status1 value='Status1'>Status1</option>
  <option $status2 value='Status2'>Status2</option>
  <option $status3 value='Status3'>Status3</option>
  <option $status4 value='Status4'>Status4</option>
  <option $status5 value='Status5'>Status5</option>
 </select>
 </td>

 <td>" . $row["value8"] . "</td></tr>";
 echo "
  <input name='send[]' value='$test' style='display: none' />". 
 "<input name='send2[]' value='$test2' style='display: none' />";
  }

  } else {
  //No data to show
  }

  $conn->close();

  ?>
 </tbody>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updatedb.php file you get array of status,send and send2

> First of all you need id of records so you can add one hidden fields
>   with id in your form like

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="$row['id']">
```

Than in your updatedb.php

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++){    
   $sql = "update tableName set status = '".$_POST['status'][$i]."',send = '".$_POST['send'][$i]."',send2 = '".$_POST['send2'][$i]."' where id = '".$_POST['id'][$i]."'";
   if(!mysql_query($sql)){
      echo "not updated".$_POST['id'][$i]; exit();  
   }
```

}

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Beware of SQL Injection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/1461181, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1461181